# How to code Fixed effects Poisson model in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to fit a fixed effects Poisson model in R using `pglm` function. I need to use both individual and time fixed effects in the model. How can I include both of them?
My example data are:

```
    library(pglm)
    library(readstata13)
    library(lmtest)
    library(MASS)

    ships<-readstata13::read.dta13("http://www.stata- 
    press.com/data/r13/ships.dta")

    ships$lnservice=log(ships$service)

    ships$time <- rep(1:8, 5)
```

I have tried using the following code to estimate the model with time and individual fixed effects:

```
    res <- pglm(accident ~ 
    op_75_79+co_65_69+co_70_74+co_75_79+lnservice,family = poisson, data = 
    ships, effect = "twoways", model="within", index = c("ship", "time"))
    summary(res)
```

The code works, however I am getting the same results as with using the model with only individual and not time effects:

```
    res <- pglm(accident ~ 
    op_75_79+co_65_69+co_70_74+co_75_79+lnservice,family = poisson, data = 
    ships, effect = "individual", model="within", index = c("ship"))
    summary(res)
```

Do you know where could be the problem? I don't expect the two models to produce the same estimates.

Comment: You may want to read [a related question on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/146434/163114), the comments are very informative.

Comment: Thanks, I have read it, but they don't have the same issue, my fixed effects estimation works well, just individual FE produces the same result as individual+time FE.

Comment: Your model specification is not complete. `pglm` imports `plm`, and similar like you have to do with the latter, you'd probably need to add `factor(time)` into your model. However, this won't work with `pglm` since it fails with the within estimator. This behavior of `pglm` seems to be intended by the author, furthermore according to [the quoted answer on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/146434/163114) this kind of model may require quite strong assumptions. However, if you know what you're doing, you could try LSDV with `glm` to calculate your within estimator.

Comment: So you are saying that `pglm` does not support time+individual fixed effects?